# Why would ldconfig be able to find a library, but not Rust?

Tags: linux, rust, linker

I'm trying to build a Rust library crate that links to `libcudart` and `libcufft`.  It works on one of my computers, but not the other and I can't figure out why.  Both are Ubuntu 20.04 with CUDA 11 and stable Rust 1.47.

```
#[link(name = "cudart")]
extern {

    fn cudaMalloc(ptr:&mut size_t, size:size_t) -> i32;
    fn cudaMemcpy(dst:*mut u8, src:*const u8, count:size_t, kind:CudaMemCopyKind ) -> i32;
    fn cudaFree(ptr:size_t) -> i32;

}
```

On the computer where it doesn't work, I get this when I try to build the crate:

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-m64" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-L" ...
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, `ldconfig` finds the library, no problem.

```
(base) john@megatron:~$ ldconfig -p | grep cudart
    libcudart.so.11.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-11.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.11.0
    libcudart.so.10.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.10.2
    libcudart.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-11.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so
    libcudart.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so
```

When I first tried it, I had CUDA 10 but the computer that worked had CUDA 11, so I installed CUDA 11 to see if that fixed it and it didn't.  It looks like the CUDA 11 installation didn't remove CUDA 10, but having more than one version isn't the problem.

I know you can add build scripts to explicitly specify dependency locations, but it wasn't necessary on my other computer and it seems like an awkward workaround that shouldn't be necessary here.  Any idea why `ldconfig` would be able to find a dependency, but not Rust?

Comment: `ldconfig` is responsible for locating libraries used in the *dynamic loader* at run time. Linking is done by the *linker*. The two are largely unrelated. The linker is not aware of `ldconfig`. Why should it be? Linking is done on the *host* machine. Running is done on the *target* machine. They sometimes may happen to be the same machine, but generally they are not.

Comment: When you manually compile/link a small C program relying on `-lcudart` do you need to provide `-L ...` or is it implicitly found? It it is not the case, may be should you `export LIBRARY_PATH=...` before building.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to n-pronouns-m.  The comment clarifying the difference between the runtime loader and build-time linker helped me solve the problem.  When I do `ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR` to find the search path of the linker, the path needed is missing.  I added it using the environment variable `LIBRARY_PATH` and it works now (important to distinguish from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).